# SSRS expression with missing column not working

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I'm trying to create an expression with a missing column. as in the column is not returned from the query but does exist in the list of fields.

The problem I'm having is that every time I do an expression and one of the parameters is from a field that doesn't have a return from query the query fails silently. the following example is looking at a field "test" that, as I said, exists in the list of fields but is not returned from the query, how can I have this is statement send "alert"??

```
=IIF(Fields!test.IsMissing,"alert",Fields!test.Value)
```

The reason that I don't return the field is that the columns are dependent on the parameters I enter in the procedure (so they could be used or not depending on what the user is asking)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question I think, you have dynamic columns which will be returns conditionally
So what you should do is,

1) Create the parameter in the parameter list and set it as the internal and assign the field value to that parameter, suppose the parameter is `dyanmicfiledvalue`

2) Change your expression as,
            `=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!dyanmicfiledvalue.value),"alert", Parameters!dyanmicfiledvalue.value )`

that should do it. Let me know in case of issues.

Or if you want to check null or empty value for that column just change as

`=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!test.value),"alert",Fields!test.value)`

Comment: It was the first thing I tried, I'll try it again to confirm,
I get very odd behaviors but what seems to do the trick is to create a calculated field and simply assign the missing parameter in that calculated field,

thus I would have the field test which recieves the value directly from the query and then I would have test_t which reads the value of test.

this would return nothing :
            =IIF(Fields!test.Value> 0,"tst","abc")
Whereas this would
            =IIF(Fields!test_t.Value> 0,"tst","abc")

your example would return nothing.

Comment: @You can assign the `NULL` to that field in query and directly test using the second expression as in the answer.

Comment: if the field would be null it would work, no question about it. however i'm using a stored procedure and I can't change the stored procedure itself. I don't want to create a temp table for every stored procedure as that would multiply my workload.